# Object becomes transparent when Rotated to backside with Matrix4

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make a cube, using Matrix4 transformations. I've made 2 walls that are standing in front of each other. The problem is when I rotate them - when one of the walls (blue) is in front of another(orange) it becomes transparent as seen in picture.

[image: Front wall becomes transparent]

If the other wall(orange) is in front of blue wall everything is OK, the front wall is not transparent.

[image: Front wall is not transparent]

This is the code to recreate

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double dx = 0.0, dy = 0.0, dz = 0.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Transform(
            transform: Matrix4.identity()
              ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.001)
              ..rotateX(dx)
              ..rotateY(dy)
              ..rotateZ(dz),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            // ..rotateZ(offset. / 180),
            child: const Center(
              child: _BuildBigCube(),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 200,
          ),
          _BuildSlider(
            value: dx,
            onChanged: (double value) {
              setState(() {
                dx = value;
              });
            },
          ),
          _BuildSlider(
            value: dy,
            onChanged: (double value) {
              setState(() {
                dy = value;
              });
            },
          ),
          _BuildSlider(
            value: dz,
            onChanged: (double value) {
              setState(() {
                dz = value;
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _BuildSlider extends StatelessWidget {
  final double value;
  final Function(double) onChanged;

  const _BuildSlider({Key? key, required this.value, required this.onChanged})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Slider(
      value: value,
      min: pi * -2,
      max: pi * 2,
      onChanged: onChanged,
    );
  }
}

class _BuildBigCube extends StatelessWidget {
  const _BuildBigCube({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        //FRONT
        Transform(
          transform: Matrix4.identity()..translate(0.0, 0.0, 100.0),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: FlutterLogo(
              size: 200,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        // BACK
        Transform(
          transform: Matrix4.identity()
            ..translate(0.0, 0.0, 100.0)
            ..invert(),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.orange,
            child: FlutterLogo(
              size: 200,
            ),
          ),
        ),

      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I'm guessing that flutter won't render the backside of a wall, but I'm not sure how to render it.

I tried rotating the wall 180 degrees, but it would still work the same.

So the question is how to render object's backside in Flutter or how to make it not transparent?

Comment: It has nothing to do with being transparent. It's just the orange one is always in front of the blue. Simply because it's two objects in a `Stack` with the orange being added last

Comment: Thanks! I'll try putting the walls to list and realign them